# Prevent Sendkeys from other Application. Prevent cheating

Tags: java, sendkeys

I programmed with a little java game; the challenge is to type the hole abc in the textbox and it give out the time used.

Now i have already built in some feature to prevent cheating:

like copy paste the hole abc
or only the middle of the abc like bcdefgh...

if you study my code you will see that I only check the first lettre A, L and Z.
A to save the start time
L to prevent cheating and copy paste only the middle of the hole abc
Z to check the hole string wich i put in the TextField. And stop the time.

Heres the Code:

```
package lvl1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class test implements KeyListener {
    private Date start_time;
    private JTextField jtf;
    private JLabel lblStatus;
    private boolean lpressed;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new test();
    }

    public test() {
        jtf = new JTextField();
        JFrame myframe = new JFrame();
        jtf.addKeyListener(this);
        lblStatus = new JLabel("Zeit:");

        myframe.setSize(700, 60);
        myframe.setTitle("ABC COOLGAME");
        myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(myframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myframe.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        myframe.add(jtf);
        myframe.add(lblStatus);
        myframe.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
        if (65 == arg0.getKeyCode()) {
            start_time = new Date();
        }
        if (8 == arg0.getKeyCode()) {
            jtf.setText("");
            jtf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        if (76 == arg0.getKeyCode()) {
            lpressed = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        Date date = new Date();

        if ((90 == arg0.getKeyCode()) & (jtf.getText().equals("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz") & (lpressed == true))) {
            lblStatus.setText("Zeit: " + (date.getTime() - start_time.getTime())
                    + " Milliseconds");
            jtf.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            lpressed = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {/* Nothing to do */} 
}
```

Now I send the Jar file to my friend and in only a few minutes i reseved a message with a record of 10 milliseconds. He told me that he send with vba the hole abc over

```
Sleep 5000  'Here he click the cursor in my textfield  
SendKeys "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

this statement will send automaticly all keys seperatly in comparison similar as I typed this on my keyboard.

Anybody know a method to prevent thes technic of cheating??

the game mustnt be secure for cheat engines other something else, but to prevent the technic above will be amazing.

Comment: I think you'll need to change from textfield (ie. accepting keyboard events) to having a-z buttons where user press buttons.

Comment: can you precise your idea?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to distinguish keyboard events from sendkeys app or normal keyboard input. So instead of typing in the alphabets, you have a bunch of buttons labeled A to Z. You now "type" the alphabets by pressing buttons.

Comment: Your game should probably have randomized text to play rather than hard coded a to z.